# deleteCharactersInRange problem

Tags: cocoa, ios, nsmutablearray

I am trying to use the deleteCharactersInRange function in a small app I wrote, but i always get an error: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with deleteCharactersInRange:'
But I defined the string i wish to use as a NSMutableString.

any ideas?

code snippets:

interface file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyappViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableString *displayString;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *displayString;
@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "MyappViewController.h"
@implementation MyappViewController
@synthesize displayString;

-(void) aFunction
{
        [displayString deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([displayString length]-1,1)];
}
@end
```

Comment: how do you create or assign value to your displayString?

Answer (score 2):

Just because you have declared displayString as an NSMutableString, that doesn't mean that it is always going to point to an NSMutableString. You have only told the compiler that that's what's supposed to be there. Check wherever displayString actually gets set. It sounds like it must be getting set to an NSString, instead of an NSMutableString.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Indeed I was using NSString methods on a NSMutableString.
However, I still have a problem: when i try to use the following method:
[displayString setString:@"."];
NSLog(@"%@", displayString);

I get NULL.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you allocing or otherwise creating an NSMutableString before that? You can't call `setString:` on displayString until you actually set displayString to point to an actual NSMutableString. `setString` won't create a string for you. You can create one with `displayString = [NSMutableString string];`